# SQLite FTS5 through PHP/PDO - How to bind values while filtering on a column name?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, fts5

In a FTS5 MATCH clause, column names used as filters are declared with an ending colon, like in:

```
... WHERE ftstable MATCH 'colname: keyword'
```

(as per https://sqlite.org/fts5.html#fts5_column_filters)

When I try to declare 'keyword' as a bound value, like in:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ftstable WHERE ftstable MATCH 'colname: :keyword'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':keyword' => 'keyword'));
```

I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 unrecognized token: ":"
```

because of the colon following the column name.

I get the same error using alternate syntax (? placeholders, bindValue(), etc.).

Does anyone know of a workaround here? Or am I missing something obvious? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have parameters in string literals; there's no interpolation done looking for them. You can, however, build an argument to `MATCH` using string concatenation:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ftstable WHERE ftstable MATCH ('colname: ' || :keyword)";
```

Comment: Oh dear! I had not even realized it was a string literal! My bad! String concatenation does the job fine. Thank you for that and apologies again.